# Cant get facebook login to be accepted by facebook

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to get the Facebook login button to give me the users detail while using firebase. On the emulator when I click the button it takes me to the Facebook site and I can continue but I get a red banner that says some permissions have not been approved by the user. I have followed this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android to make sure I have added them all but I could have messed something up.

```
lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager


var id = ""
var firstName = ""
var middleName = ""
var lastName = ""
var name = ""
var picture = ""
var email = ""
var accessToken = ""

companion object {
    private const val RC_SIGN_IN = 120
}

private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
var temp : String = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)
    val callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

    //Try signInActivity.this as context
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    val signInBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.sign_in_btn)
    val buttonFacebookLogin = findViewById<LoginButton>(R.id.login_button_facebook)

// Initialize Facebook Login button
        buttonFacebookLogin.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile")
        buttonFacebookLogin.setOnClickListener {
            LoginManager.getInstance()
                .logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("public_profile", "email"))
        }

    LoginManager.getInstance()
        .registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult?> {
            override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult?) {
                println("Success Login")
                getUserProfile(loginResult?.accessToken, loginResult?.accessToken?.userId)
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                println(" Login cancelled")
            }

            override fun onError(exception: FacebookException) {
                println(" Login error")
            }
        })
```

`

```
@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
fun getUserProfile(token: AccessToken?, userId: String?) {

    val parameters = Bundle()
    parameters.putString(
        "fields",
        "id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, name, picture, email"
    )
    GraphRequest(token,
        "/$userId/",
        parameters,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        GraphRequest.Callback { response ->
            val jsonObject = response.jsonObject

            // Facebook Access Token
            // You can see Access Token only in Debug mode.
            // You can't see it in Logcat using Log.d, Facebook did that to avoid leaking user's access token.
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true)
                FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS)
            }
            accessToken = token.toString()

            // Facebook Id
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                if (jsonObject.has("id")) {
                    val facebookId = jsonObject.getString("id")
                    Log.i("Facebook Id: ", facebookId.toString())
                    id = facebookId.toString()
                } else {
                    Log.i("Facebook Id: ", "Not exists")
                    id = "Not exists"
                }
            }


            // Facebook First Name
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                if (jsonObject.has("first_name")) {
                    val facebookFirstName = jsonObject.getString("first_name")
                    Log.i("Facebook First Name: ", facebookFirstName)
                    firstName = facebookFirstName
                } else {
                    Log.i("Facebook First Name: ", "Not exists")
                    firstName = "Not exists"
                }
            }


            // Facebook Middle Name
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                if (jsonObject.has("middle_name")) {
                    val facebookMiddleName = jsonObject.getString("middle_name")
                    Log.i("Facebook Middle Name: ", facebookMiddleName)
                    middleName = facebookMiddleName
                } else {
                    Log.i("Facebook Middle Name: ", "Not exists")
                    middleName = "Not exists"
                }
            }


            // Facebook Last Name
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                if (jsonObject.has("last_name")) {
                    val facebookLastName = jsonObject.getString("last_name")
                    Log.i("Facebook Last Name: ", facebookLastName)
                    lastName = facebookLastName
                } else {
                    Log.i("Facebook Last Name: ", "Not exists")
                    lastName = "Not exists"
                }
            }


            // Facebook Name
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                if (jsonObject.has("name")) {
                    val facebookName = jsonObject.getString("name")
                    Log.i("Facebook Name: ", facebookName)
                    name = facebookName
                } else {
                    Log.i("Facebook Name: ", "Not exists")
                    name = "Not exists"
                }
            }


            // Facebook Profile Pic URL
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                if (jsonObject.has("picture")) {
                    val facebookPictureObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("picture")
                    if (facebookPictureObject.has("data")) {
                        val facebookDataObject = facebookPictureObject.getJSONObject("data")
                        if (facebookDataObject.has("url")) {
                            val facebookProfilePicURL = facebookDataObject.getString("url")
                            Log.i("Facebook Profile Pic URL: ", facebookProfilePicURL)
                            picture = facebookProfilePicURL
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("Facebook Profile Pic URL: ", "Not exists")
                    picture = "Not exists"
                }
            }

            // Facebook Email
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                if (jsonObject.has("email")) {
                    val facebookEmail = jsonObject.getString("email")
                    Log.i("Facebook Email: ", facebookEmail)
                    email = facebookEmail
                } else {
                    Log.i("Facebook Email: ", "Not exists")
                    email = "Not exists"
                }
            }

            openDetailsActivity()
        }).executeAsync()
}

fun isLoggedIn(): Boolean {
    val accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
    val isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired
    return isLoggedIn
}


fun logOutUser() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
}
```

Logs regarding Facebook

```
2021-11-25 20:56:08.366 9837-9837/com.example.go4lunch W/com.facebook.UserSettingsManager: 

Please set a value for AutoLogAppEventsEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect app install, app launch and in-app purchase events automatically. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android#disable-auto-events.
2021-11-25 20:56:08.366 9837-9837/com.example.go4lunch W/com.facebook.UserSettingsManager: You haven't set a value for AdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect Advertiser ID for better advertising and analytics results. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android#disable-auto-events.
2021-11-25 20:56:08.414 9837-9873/com.example.go4lunch W/GraphRequest: Starting with v13 of the SDK, a client token must be embedded in your client code before making Graph API calls. Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#client-token to learn how to implement this change.
2021-11-25 20:56:08.419 9837-9879/com.example.go4lunch W/GraphRequest: Starting with v13 of the SDK, a client token must be embedded in your client code before making Graph API calls. Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#client-token to learn how to implement this change.
2021-11-25 20:56:08.437 9837-9882/com.example.go4lunch W/com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol: Apps that target Android API 30+ (Android 11+) cannot call Facebook native apps unless the package visibility needs are declared. Please follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting/#faq_267321845055988 to make the declaration.
2021-11-25 20:56:08.452 9837-9880/com.example.go4lunch W/GraphRequest: Starting with v13 of the SDK, a client token must be embedded in your client code before making Graph API calls. Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#client-token to learn how to implement this change.
2021-11-25 20:56:09.348 9837-9880/com.example.go4lunch W/GraphRequest: Starting with v13 of the SDK, a client token must be embedded in your client code before making Graph API calls. Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#client-token to learn how to implement this change.
2021-11-25 20:56:15.563 9837-9837/com.example.go4lunch W/class com.facebook.login.LoginManager: You're calling logging in Facebook with an activity supports androidx activity result APIs. Please follow our document to upgrade to new APIs to avoid overriding onActivityResult().
2021-11-25 20:56:15.798 9837-9837/com.example.go4lunch W/com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol: Apps that target Android API 30+ (Android 11+) cannot call Facebook native apps unless the package visibility needs are declared. Please follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting/#faq_267321845055988 to make the declaration.
2021-11-25 20:56:15.798 9837-9873/com.example.go4lunch W/com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol: Apps that target Android API 30+ (Android 11+) cannot call Facebook native apps unless the package visibility needs are declared. Please follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting/#faq_267321845055988 to make the declaration.
```